# Importing a sql file to mysql on an ubuntu server failing

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to import a sql file that is on the server using the following command in the terminal

```
mysql -u NAME -p DBNAME < path/to/FILE.sql
```

when i do that it asks for the password, after inputting the password nothing happens. I check the database and no tables have been added.

**Note:**

- DBNAME is created in the mysql database.
- I have also tried the following syntax in mysql and also that didn't work

`mysql> source PATH/TO/FILE.sql`

Please Help :D

Comment: _“after inputting the password nothing happens”_ – there is no output while the import is running. So if your SQL dump is big enough, it might take a while to process ...

Comment: @CBroe yeah i thought so, but then i kept checking and still nothing. 
Do you think there is another way i could do this ?

Comment: How big is your SQL file? How long did you wait for it to finish?

Comment: @CBroe its 1.5MB and i have been trying for hours now

Answer (score 0):

The sql file was corrupt, all i had to do was delete it and upload it once again. thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can trying with

1. Create the database for import the tables:

   mysql -u root -p

   create database database_name;

   exit

   mysql -u user -p databasename < databasename.sql